# MVC Azure can't find view or master with default route but works locally

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, azure, razor

I have an MVC website that works fine running locally but when I deploy it to my Azure Website I get this error for every webpage except the Home Index page.

```
The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Sales/Index.aspx
~/Views/Sales/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/Sales/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Sales/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
```

I can provide more information, if necessary, but I haven't been able to find anyone with the same issue in all the reports of this issue. Most people legitimately have the issue of the file in the wrong place. But, my structure of Controllers and Views are fine, they work locally. It only fails to find the Views when its deployed to my Azure Website.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the properties of each of the views I had to change the Build Action to Content and the publish actually deployed the .cshtml files.

Comment: In asp.net core RC2 you do this in the project.json. You included the "Views" folder in the "publishOptions": { "include": [] } section

Answer (score 2):

For those with an ASP.NET Core application, the solution was to add "Views" to the `publishOptions.include` array:

```
"publishOptions": {
  "include": [
    "wwwroot",
    "Views",
    "web.config"
  ]
},
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I started with an 'empty' project and needed to add this line to get it working.

Comment: I think you can use   "**/*.cshtml" in place of "Views"

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your View is really copied to the server.

From Visual Studio, right-click on view, select "Properties" and check "Copy to Output Directory" property. Maybe you have "Do not copy" selected?

For deployment options on Azure, I'd recommend [this article](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/).

It could also be a problem with routing - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2103223/asp-net-mvc-routing-in-azure?rq=1).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to check the Copy to output. That wasn't the fix but, I also noticed the build action field was empty and changed all the views to content like the Home views and they are actually working now on azure. Thank you very much for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and the view was removed from the .csproj file via a co-worker's git merge. Took me a while to figure this out. Hopefully this helps someone.